# Js execute mechanism for script block

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use closure library, and Google remind us to use the library carefully:

This does not work:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  // DON'T DO THIS.
  goog.require('goog.dom');
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
```

I know why, beacuse `goog.require` will add scripts related `goog.dom` dynamically, and it will execute `goog.dom.xx` immediately while the `goog.dom` script is not downloaded yet, then it will throw errors.

However I wonder why this works:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
</script>
<script>
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
```

The `goog.dom` will called immediately after the `goog.require`, but why it does not throw the error.

It seems that this is caused by that the two pieces of codes are resided at two `script` blocks.

So I wonder if anyone can explain the JavaScript execution mechanism at different `script` block and different location(inside head or body)?

---

Update for Romain's answser:

> the parser sees this:
>
> ```
> <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
> <script>
>   goog.require('goog.dom');
> </script>
> <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/dom.js"></script>
> <script>
>   var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
> </script>
> ```

Though the `<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/dom.js"></script>` is added before the `var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom....`, the `dom.js` is to be downloade, does the `goog.dom.create....` will be executed after the `dom.js` is completely downloaded and executed?  But I have heard that the js execution is asynchronous. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the "Getting started" page:

> The goog.require() call adds the code for goog.dom.createDom()
>   immediately before the script tag containing the line var newHeader =
>   goog.dom.createDom('h1').

the script loader loads the scripts by inserting script elements into the DOM. It inserts them **after the "current script element"**. This is why you need to "close" the script element before you use functions of the dynamically loaded scripts.

if this is your source html:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
</script>
<script>
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
```

the parser sees this:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
</script>
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/dom.js"></script>
<script>
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
```

but if your source is this:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
```

the parser sees this:

```
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
  var newHeader = goog.dom.createDom('h1');
</script>
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/dom.js"></script>
```

which of course doesn't work.

Script execution is synchronous. Downloading a script with a script element blocks the execution of scripts (and also the rendering of the page). This is why you should not put unnecessary script elements into `<head>`. This blocks the parser and therefore the rendering of everything that comes after (a.k.a your document) until your scripts are downloaded.

In HTML5 there is an attribute for [script tags (`async`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) that declares that the browser should not wait for the script to download. But the default behaviour is to wait.

Comment: So script  element inside `<head>` will blocks the execution of scripts? how about the scripts inside the `<body>`?

Comment: No. That was just an example. In **all** cases (also in `<body>`) the browser waits until the script is downloaded and executed before it continues on. The difference is that if you put a script into `<head>` the browser has to wait before it begins to draw the contents of `<body>`. While if you put the script tags at the end of your body tag, "nothing" has to wait.

Comment: and therefore it seems like the page would load faster